# Why does m2e add dependency always zero

Tags: maven, dependencies, m2e

When I try to add a dependency in pom.xml, the result always zero.
Like, I input "log4j", the select dependency UI show results for 'log4j' (0)
How can I search the result from the central repository?
This is my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>G:/Maven/repository</localRepository>
  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

  <proxies>
  </proxies>
  <servers>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
  </mirrors>


  <profiles>
  </profiles>

</settings>
```

Comment: Have you configured to download the index in Eclipse?

Comment: I go to "maven repositories" view  rebuild index on the "global Repositories"->"central(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)" option.the progress view show it is rebuild success,but it is not useful,the problem is still.

Comment: My eclipse version is 4.1.2, m2e version is 1.0.2, maven version is 3.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Why not using just as simple as possible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>G:/Maven/repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```